# Turning a CommPorts Off

Tags: python, pyserial

I am currently writing a code to turn a serial port off and the code I have wrote has no errors but its not doing its function.

```
def health_check(self):
    print("getting health report")
    ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
    for p in ports:
        print(p)
    ser = serial.Serial("COM1" , 9600)
    ser.close()
```

This code currently detects if a port is open. I am just trying to do simple things with it first.

This is the output,

getting health report

COM1 - Communications Port (COM1)

port is open

Comment: Can you please add the print output as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "turn a serial port off", it's always on. Can be open or closed, but still always on.

Comment: @Neamus you call `ser.open()` and the port is open. you call `ser.close()` and the port is closed. it's like a file. do you understand opening and closing the file? except you can delete the file, but cannot delete (or turn off) the port =)

Comment: Yes i understand what you saying.